# Node.js: There's something wrong with this, and I don't know what

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm helping my friend with some code, and I tried to fix the problem in it, but neither of us can figure it out, so here I am, asking people on StackOverflow for help!

```
var colors = require('colors/safe');
var chalkAnimation = require('chalk-animation');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
  var Username = prompt('[ⓘ SET UP INFO ] - Please start the connect process by typing in: "mh!startup" ');
  if (Username == 'mh!startup') {

const RainbowMPPHAXX = chalkAnimation.rainbow(`███╗░░░███╗██████╗░██████╗░  ██╗░░██╗░█████╗░██╗░░██╗██╗░░██╗
████╗░████║██╔══██╗██╔══██╗  ██║░░██║██╔══██╗╚██╗██╔╝╚██╗██╔╝
██╔████╔██║██████╔╝██████╔╝  ███████║███████║░╚███╔╝░░╚███╔╝░
██║╚██╔╝██║██╔═══╝░██╔═══╝░  ██╔══██║██╔══██║░██╔██╗░░██╔██╗░
██║░╚═╝░██║██║░░░░░██║░░░░░  ██║░░██║██║░░██║██╔╝╚██╗██╔╝╚██╗
╚═╝░░░░░╚═╝╚═╝░░░░░╚═╝░░░░░  ╚═╝░░╚═╝╚═╝░░╚═╝╚═╝░░╚═╝╚═╝░░╚═╝         `);
  }
setTimeout(function() {
    RainbowMPPHAXX.start(); // Animation resumes
}, 0);
setTimeout(function(){ console.info(colors.cyan("[ ⓘ  CONNECT INFO ] - Connecting to MPP HAXX . . . ")); }, 700);
setTimeout(function(){ console.info(colors.green("[ ⓘ  CONNECT INFO ] - Successfully connected to MPP HAXX! ")); }, 1700);
setTimeout(function(){ console.info(colors.cyan("[ ⓘ  CONNECT INFO ] - Connecting to MPP HAXX login . ."));  }, 1800);
setTimeout(function(){ console.info(colors.green("[ ⓘ  CONNECT INFO ] - Successfully connected to MPP HAXX login! start up successful! :D"));  }, 2000);
/*Thanks Alex for helping with some wrapping in the code!*/
/*MPP HAXX LOGIN*/
var KnowsUsername = true;
var KnowsEmail = true;
var KnowsPassword = true;
setTimeout(function () {
  var Username = prompt('[LOGIN QUESTION] - What is your username?');
  if (Username == '') {
    KnowsUsername = true;
    console.info(colors.green('[ ⓘ  LOGIN INFO] - Correct username!'));

    var Email = prompt('[LOGIN QUESTION] - What is your E-mail?');
    if (Email == '') {
      KnowsEmail = true;
      console.info(colors.green('[ ⓘ  LOGIN INFO] - Correct E-mail!'));

      var Password = prompt('[LOGIN QUESTION] - What is your password?');
      if (Password == '') {
        KnowsPassword = true;
        const RainbowLoading = chalkAnimation.rainbow(`Loading...`);
          setTimeout(function() {
            RainbowLoading.start(); // Animation resumes
          }, 0);
        console.info(colors.green('[ ⓘ  LOGIN INFO] - Correct password!'));
        setTimeout(function(){console.info(colors.cyan(`[ ⓘ  2FA INFO ] - This is the final last step of the verification process! since you have gotten all of the login questions correct so far. We will now send you an E-mail to your E-mail: "${Email}" with the 2FA code. If you don't recive it in your main inbox please click on this link: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?tab=rm&ogbl#spam `)); }, 7000);

      } else {
        KnowsPassword = false;
        console.error(colors.red('[LOGIN ERROR] - Aww! it looks like ' + '"' + Password + '"' + " is not your password. Try again!" ));
      }
    } else {
      KnowsEmail = false;
      console.error(colors.red('[LOGIN ERROR] - Aww! it looks like ' + '"' + Email + '"' + " is not your E-mail. Try again!" ));
    }
  } else {
    KnowsUsername = false;
    console.error(colors.red('[LOGIN ERROR] - Aww! it looks like ' + '"' + Username + '"' + " is not your username. Try again!" ));
  }
}, 2100);
```

He uses VSC (Visual Studio Code) to see what it does, and apparently it doesn't give the "Loading..." thing rainbow text, I'm hoping somebody knows what's going on, because I don't